# How do I get MySQL tables to update each other?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to programming so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to get MySQL tables to update each other. For example: When I insert data into a Primary Key column in one table, it does not appear in it's Foreign Key column in another table.

Does anyone have any advice on this issue?

Thank you!

Additional Information: I used phpMyAdmin to create my tables and then added SQL code to create the Foreign Keys. Example of code is below.

```
ALTER TABLE CourseSchedule
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CourseId)
REFERENCES Course(CourseId)
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide your sql commands that does not work as expected.

Comment: I actually used phpMyAdmin to create the two tables and then used the following SQL code to add the Foreign Key. 

ALTER TABLE CourseSchedule
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CourseId)
REFERENCES Course(CourseId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what we have here is a slight misunderstanding of the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> For storage engines supporting foreign keys, MySQL rejects any INSERT
>   or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a
>   child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the
>   parent table.
>
> When an UPDATE or DELETE operation affects a key value in the parent
>   table that has matching rows in the child table, the result depends on
>   the referential action specified using ON UPDATE and ON DELETE
>   subclauses of the FOREIGN KEY clause. MySQL supports five options
>   regarding the action to be taken, listed here

What your foreign key actually does is to make sure that you cannot insert values into your `CourseSchedule` table that do not correspond to an entry in the `Courses` table.

To give you an example, suppose you were to try to enter schedule a python course for every wednesday at 9:00 but you dont' actually have an entry for python in your Courses table. Then mysql will refuse to create that entry. Mysql cannot do the reverse. It doesn't know details about your python course. So it cannot automatically create a entry in the Courses table for you. Similarly, if oyu created an entr in the courses table. Mysql cannot automatically create a CourseSchedule for you because it doesn't know at what time it should be scheduled.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up the confusion as to what foreign keys are. So, as far as my question goes, is it possible for that information to populate into multiple tables? The database I am making is for an online application I am creating for my senior project. I'm trying to follow proper database fundamentals but at this rate, it would be much easier to just put all the data into one table.

Comment: LIke I have already explained, you need to have another sql query. You need to get the LAST_INSERT_ID from your first query and use it in your second.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.